# angular.foreach inside a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a function that returns a promise and inside that function I have an angular.forEach that returns a promise.
Here is an example code:

```
function func1() {
    func2(demoText, demoObject).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

function func2(demoText, demoObject) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var returnString = "someReturnString";
    var keepGoing = true;
    var loopPromises = [];

    angular.forEach(demoObject, function(value, key) {
        if(keepGoing) {
            var deferred2 = $q.defer();
            loopPromises.push(deferred2.promise);

            if(value.type == 'other') {
                someService.getDataFromServer()
                .then(function(serverResponse) {
                    returnString = serverResponse;
                    deferred2.resolve();
                });
                keepGoing = false;
            }
            else {
                deferred2.resolve();
            }                                        
        }
    });

    return $q.all(loopPromises).then(function () {
        deferred.resolve(returnString);
        return deferred.promise;
    });
}
```

Now the returned value is "someReturnString" which means that the value is retuned before I'm getting the result from the server.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: AngularJS version 1.6.9